# Can't pass a Map<Long, String> to a constructor with the argument Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>. Why?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class:

```
class MySelectBox {
    public MySelectBox(Provider<Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>> providerArrayIdToLabel) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to pass this in code that uses this class:

```
new MySelectBox(new Provider<Map<Long, String>>{
    ... my implementation of Provider ...
});
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
The constructor MySelectBox(new Provider<Map<Long,String>>(){}) is undefined
```

Why? Why is the method undefined? What should I change in the constructor's signature to make it accept `Provider<Map<Long, String>>`

Note: the Provider interface is:

```
public interface Provider<T> extends javax.inject.Provider<T> {
  T get();
}
```

Comment: Your MySelectBox instantiation code doesn't look like it even compiles. Can you double-check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the declaration of the MySelectBox constructor to this:

```
public MySelectBox(Provider<? extends Map<? extends Long, ? extends String>> providerArrayIdToLabel)
```

Comment: `? extends Long` will accept `Long` and... what else ? (the same for `String`).

Comment: I would still need to pass different object types, not just ? extends Long or ? extends String.

Comment: I will accept this as a correct answer although all of the answers below are neat and valid solutions.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answers, your title is wrong and does not reflect the question. You *can* pass a `Map<Long, String>` into a `Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>`. That's not the problem. You can't pass a `Provider<X>` to a `Provider<Y>` if X and Y are different (here X is `Map<Long, String>` and Y is `Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>`). It doesn't matter if X is a subtype of Y. This is just like you can't pass `Provider<String>` to a `Provider<Object>` even though String is a subtype of Object. However, if you use a wildcard at the top level, that will allow you to allow subtypes -- you can pass `Provider<X>` to a `Provider<? extends Y>`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the effect of the Java generics being invariant.

Since that map is passed to the constructor, I think the best fix would be to declare the key and value types as class generics, so each instance will hold a map of specific keys and values:

```
class MySelectBox<K, V> {
    public MySelectBox(Provider<Map<K, V>> map) {}
}
```

Now you can safely write:

```
new MySelectBox<Long, String>(new Provider<Map<Long, String>>());
```

Comment: I would change MySelectBox<K, V> to be MySelectBox<K extends Long, V extends String> to reflect the type restrictions implied in the original post.  Your answer is clean and wise.

Comment: @ditkin: `? extends Long/String` is pretty useless, as both those classes are final. It would make sense though (depending on the actual usecase) to have `? super Long, ? super String`.

Comment: @ditkin: besides, the original post seems to imply no restriction: `? extends Object` means just `?` or `T` if you need to give it a name.

Comment: why make the class generic if it the type variables are not needed in the rest of the class?

Comment: I suppose that class exposes or uses something like `getProvider()` or `getProviderMap()` and a bit of type safety can help there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
    new MySelectBox(new Provider<Map<?, ?>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<Long, String> get() {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Here's my attempts at an explanation (which might be wrong, because I also have a hard time with generics):

The compiler doesn't know that a Provider only creates objects. It thinks that a `Provider<Map<?, ?>>` is an object that is able to hold instances of `Map<?, ?>` (just like a `List<Map<?, ?>>`). And since a `Provider<Map<?, ?>>` is supposed to be able to hold maps containing anything as keys, and anything as values, a `Provider<Map<Long, String>>` is not a valid type substitution. Indeed, a `Provider<Map<Long, String>>` can only hold instances of `Map<Long, String>`.

Comment: Provider<Long, String> is not a valid type substitution. You meant Map<Long, String>, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll fix it. Thanks.